# c#: Why does opening a read-only file for read access fails

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to open a file in a windows service. But am getting Access denied error.
I am using the below code.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open('sample.txt', 
FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

As you see here, i am only opening with read permission. And the file already has a read-only permission checked in the properties dialog. But, still i can't understand why i am getting this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be that the user the code is running under does not have permissions to read this file?

Comment: can you post the exact exception please? Can you try running your application as Administrator? Is the file being accessed by another program?

Comment: Also, are you disposing the filestream? maybe it is still open somewhere in memory...

Comment: how to find the user who's running the code and the permissions for that user?

Comment: No, i have'nt disposed. Just i added this single line of code only.
Got this exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: if you are debugging the code through VS, open VS as administrator.

Comment: Check the file and make sure it's security is set to "Everyone".

Comment: I found the answer here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514462/error-when-opening-file-for-reading-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

Make sure to dispose the filestream by wrapping it in a using statement:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open('sample.exe', FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) 
{
}
```

Also, try adding `FileShare.Read` instead of `FileShare.ReadWrite` as a parameter to the Open statement, as FileAccess is set to Read.

Make sure the user has permission to access the file: right click on the file and check the security tab - set read to "Everyone". If that doesn't work, set Full Control to Everyone as a sanity test.

Comment: But when i created a new project in VS, and added this same code, it is working fine. Can you explain why?

Comment: so it it working now? There is a slight difference in the FileShare parameter. You were using ReadWrite while the FileAccess was set to Read, the one I posted is using Read.

Comment: Both FileShare is working in the new project. But both are not working the old one. How can the permissions differ for specif projects?

Comment: honestly, do a file comparison in NotePad++ or something to find the differences. It could be a reference, or a file permission or something. Without more info, I can't help - you only provided a single line of code.

Comment: i created a class library with this single line of code. When i added this class lib to my project, it is not working. But when i created a standalone project, the same code is working


(My previous reply is incorrect. I tried only FileShare.Read in both)

Comment: @user1666620: +1. This works as expected for `Read-only` files. But only `FileStream stream = File.Open('sample.exe', FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)` doesn't work for `Read-only` files.