# Error when opening file for reading in c#

Tags: c#, .net, file-permissions

This code works in a normal project.

```
string path = @"...\My_App_Data\Sample.xml";
Using(FileStream fs = File.Open(path,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{

}
```

But, when i put the same code into a method in a class library and then call the method, i am getting UnAuthorizedAccessException.
NOTE: The Sample.xml is in a My_App_Data folder in the solution explorer.

Even if i open the VS.net with admin rights, i get the same error.

Can anyone resolve this. Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is running in the bin/debug folder so you need to find the path relative to that.

If you made a folder in your root solution it would (possibly) be:

`@"..\\..\\..\\My_App_Data\\Sample.xml"`

Basically.. 
up from debug \ up from bin \ up from project folder \My_App_Data\Sample.xml

I also escaped the \

Comment: @khcha22 remember to change this when you deploy the app, as the directories would change. Best to make it a setting or something along those lines